# Small python calculator bug

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this simple python calculator, but there is an odd bug.

The first equation you enter nothing happens.
the second time you try it works.
the next time you try nothing happens.
if you try again after that it works.
ect. ect. ect.

Here is a example (sorry if its confusing):

(program) enter your equation:
(me) 1 - 1
*nothing happens*
(program) (prompts you to enter again)
(me) 1 - 1
(program) 0
(program) enter your equation:
(me) 1 - 1
*nothing happens*
(program) (prompts you to enter again)
(me) 1 - 1
(program) 0
(program) enter your equation:
(me) 1 - 1
*nothing happens*

Here is a photo of what this looks like:
[calc.py photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwWU4.png)
This happens no matter what numbers or operator you use.

Here is my full code:

```
while True:
  print('Enter an equation:')
  input('')
  while True:
       x, op, y = input().split()
       x = int(x)
       y = int(y)
       if op == '+':
            print(x + y)
            break
       elif op == '-':
            print(x - y)
            break
       elif op == '*':
            print(x * y)
            break
       elif op == '/':
            print(x / y)
            break
       else:
            print('Invalid equation!')
            break
```

Comment: You never save the first input you receive to a variable, I also can't see why its there at all (line 3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have this `input()` call that does nothing and swalls a line each time :)
also, you don't need the inner loop at all

```
   while True:
       print('Enter an equation:')
       x, op, y = input().split()  # <-- just one is enough 
       x = int(x)
       y = int(y)
       if op == '+':
            print(x + y)
       elif op == '-':
            print(x - y)
       elif op == '*':
            print(x * y)=
       elif op == '/':
            print(x / y)
       else:
            print('Invalid equation!')
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two `input()` calls, that is the problem, use one and store its result in a variable, and use that in place of the second call (also, why do you have two `while True` loops, if you want your program to keep reading equations, just use one loop and remove the `break` from it):

```
while True:
    eq = input('Enter an equation:')
    x, op, y = eq.split()
    x = int(x)
    y = int(y)
    if op == '+':
        print(x + y)
    elif op == '-':
        print(x - y)
    elif op == '*':
        print(x * y)
    elif op == '/':
        print(x / y)
    else:
        print('Invalid equation!')
```